# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_FUNCTION

Tags: php, parsing

I get this error in my PHP code:

> PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_FUNCTION in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\webroot\www.novotempo.org.br\lib\Twitter.php on line 54

The line in question:

```
define('DEBUG',false);
```

Searching the net I found that this usually occurs when you´re using PHP 4.xx, but I´m using 5.2.6 (Just checked it using `phpinfo()`).

I tried locally, and in two other external hosts, but it keeps returning the same message.

Why does this happen? How can I fix it?

Comment: The true problem is probably one one of the lines before it

Comment: Can you post more of the code (a few lines above and a few beneath)?

Comment: Inside a class method, I got this error when I commented an `if` statement but forgot to comment the closing brace. That put my next line outside of the function definition. It was a call to a static class function, which PHP saw as an unexpected string literal, I suppose.

Answer (score 17):

If you are trying to `DEFINE` something inside of a class but outside of a function, you are going to get this error.

(Normally the only place PHP will be looking for a function and not expecting a string is in a class, outside of a method)

IE: Your code should **not** look like this:

```
class myClass
{
    define("DEBUG", true);
    function myFunc()
     {
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this, resolved an annoying issue quite quickly for me.

I'd also like to add that the use of hyphens in constant names doesn't work and is apparently expected behaviour. It seems as though the echo tries to evaluate mathematics (minus) on the words.

```
<?php
define('THIS-IS-A-TEST','Testing');
echo THIS-IS-A-TEST;
?>
```

Returns '0'

```
<?php
define('THIS_IS_A_TEST','Testing');
echo THIS_IS_A_TEST;
?>
```

Returns 'Testing'

Comment: Actually, you will see `PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant: THIS - assumed 'THIS'` in the console log.